# Tunring my android to beacon and detecting

Tags: java, android

Is this right way of doing? AM using this samples https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

> ```
>    public class App extends Application
>     implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {
> private final String TAG = "Application ";
> protected static final Region beaconRegion = new Region("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6", null, null, null);
> protected BeaconManager beaconManager = null;
> private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
> private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
> protected static String sLog = "";
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>     logIt(TAG, beaconRegion.getId1()+"onCreate - In"+beaconRegion.getUniqueId());
>     beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
>     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
>     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
>             setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));//iBeacon (tutti)
>     //--- wake up the app when a beacon is seen
>     regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, beaconRegion);
>     //--- activate power saver
>     backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
>     beaconManager.bind(this);
>     logIt(TAG, "onCreate - Out");
> }
> private void logIt (String TAG, String msg) {
>     sLog += TAG + msg + "\n";
>     Log.w(TAG, msg);
> }
> //-------------------------//
> //--- BootstrapNotifier ---//
> //-------------------------//
> @Override
> public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
>     String msg = "didDetermineStateForRegion ";
>     switch(state) {
>         case MonitorNotifier.INSIDE:
>             msg +="(INSIDE)";
>             break;
>         case MonitorNotifier.OUTSIDE:
>             msg +="(OUTSIDE)";
>             break;
>         default:
>             msg +="(state=" +state +")";
>             break;
>     }
>     logIt(TAG, msg);
> }
> @Override
> public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
>     logIt(TAG, "didEnterRegion - In");
>     try {
>         beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
>         logIt(TAG,"dER - startRangingBeaconsInRegion OK");
>     } catch (RemoteException e) {
>         logIt(TAG, "dER - startRangingBeaconsInRegion Err " +e);
>     }
>     logIt(TAG, "didEnterRegion - Out");
> }
> @Override
> public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
>     logIt(TAG, "didExitRegion - In");
>     try {
>         beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
>         logIt(TAG,"dXR - stopRangingBeaconsInRegion OK");
>     } catch (RemoteException e) {
>         logIt(TAG, "dXR - stopRangingBeaconsInRegion Err " +e);
>     }
>     logIt(TAG, "didExitRegion - Out");
> }
> //----------------------//
> //--- BeaconConsumer ---//
> //----------------------//
> @Override
> public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
>     logIt(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect - In");
>     beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
>     logIt(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect - Out");
> }
> //---------------------//
> //--- RangeNotifier ---//
> //---------------------//
> @Override
> public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
>     logIt(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion - " +beacons.size() +" beacons");
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), beaconRegion.getId1()+" beacon detected "+beacons.size(),
>             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     for(Beacon beac: beacons)
>     {
>         System.out.println(beac.getId1()+"id 1"+TAG);
>        if(beac.getId1().equals("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")/send notification
>     }
> }
>  }
> ```

So Basically that class, which extends application am listening to beacons around.  Below, is how am turning my  phone into a beacon.I am doing this inside an activity on click of button. So there is two phones with  app downloaded on both, once he clicks on one app the button I want the other phone to detect it since i have implemented in extends application class.

the turn ur android to beacon code.

> ```
>               Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
>                         .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6") // UUID for beacon
>                         .setId2("1") // Major for beacon
>                         .setId3("5") // Minor for beacon
>                         .setManufacturer(0x004C) // Radius Networks.0x0118  Change this for other beacon layouts//0x004C for iPhone
>                         .setTxPower(-56) // Power in dB
>                         .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
>                         .build();
>                 BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
>                         .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
>                 beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(MenuActivity.this, beaconParser);
>                 beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
>                         Log.e("tag", "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
>                     }
>                     @Override
>                     public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
>                         Log.i("tag", "Advertisement start succeeded.");
>                         Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "advertisement start succeeded",
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                         System.out.println("startedddddddddddd");
>                     }
>                 });
>                 //   beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising();
>             }
>             catch(Exception o)
>             {
>                 System.out.println("affda "+o.getMessage());
>             }
> ```

I am also havig an issue, that didenterregion and didRangeBeaconsInRegion are fired many times, so am sending many notification to the user multiple times. its not user friendly.

Comment: Don't post comments on your own question trying to explain it.  If you have more information that you want to add to your question, [edit] your question and add it there.

Answer (score 2):

The `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback is supposed to get called many times -- that's how ranging works.  It is called approximately once per second when the beacon is detected to tell you it is there and give you a distance estimate.

If you want to fire a notification only once for the first time you get a call to this method, then you can set a flag for this specific beacon.

Here is an example of some code you might use to do that:

```
// Add this to the top of your class
private HashMap<String,Boolean> mAlreadySentNotification = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();

...

// Add this to the inside of your didRangeBeaconsInRegion method
if (mAlreadySentNotification.get(beacon.toString())) {
  mAlreadySentNotification.put(beacon.toString(), true);
  // Send notification here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution is good but it has a bug. For ex. I detected beacon 1, and i set this beacon 1 to true so that i sent one notification only. However I do need to reset beacon 1 back to false , so that i sent notification again in the future like 30 minutes later maybe or a one day later ? How do I handle such case.